# Missing style file (previously worked)

Tags: packages, installing, texmf

Before I start, this is probably closely related to [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files), but I can't figure it out.

Previously I have had a file compiling and working fine. I am not sure what has changed, but all of a sudden today I have been receiving (Linux Mint 10.10)

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def)) (./xy.sty

! I can't find file `xy'.

l.32 \input xy
```

I have tried to

```
sudo texhash
```

I have also tried just putting xy.sty in the directory, which didn't work either.

I tried the following:

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME

/home/foo/texmf
```

This folder does not exist, but it appears I have a hidden folder, i.e. `/home/foo/.texmf-var`

I tried to install the `xy.sty` file in `/home/foo/.texmf-var/tex/latex`
If I call it `xy.sty`, it gives the same error message

If it is just called 'xy' I get

```
 TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
```

Basically - I don't know what I have done, what I can do to fix it, and if I am going to break anything else if I keep fiddling!

**Edit**: I should also note the following. Line 6 of the tex file is
`\usepackage[all]{xy}`

While the error seems to refer to line 32?

Comment: `kpsewhich xy.sty`is the command to find xy in your distribution. With OS X I have `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xy.sty`and I think xy.sty exists inside TL from a lot of years. A complete example will be very useful

Comment: @Altermundus - this is just blank (I guess xy.sty really isn't found!). I don't have a /usr/local/texlive folder for what its worth

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive` is only for OS X . This is different on Linux but what is your tex distribution ?

Comment: Please use code blocks not quotation blocks for code and compiler messages. Inline code can be marked with backticks.

Comment: how to install xy package in ubuntu in kile

Comment: @mahi: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 9):

Besides `xy.sty`, you also need `xy.tex`. The error message belongs to line 32 of `xy.sty`, there's the command `\input xy`. This means `xy.sty` has been found but not the `xy.tex` file.

Just install the complete [`xypic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xypic) package. On my system, with TeX Live 2011 pretest, the `xypic` directory contains 63 files.

Comment: @Stefan - thank you I have managed to get it working again. I wonder what happened??

Comment: @Stefan I think `xypic` directory is a part of TL 2009 (and before) and it's not normal to install the complete  `xypic` package

Comment: And just to add one more comment - I just installed the texlive-pictures package, which has xy-pic in it, and let it do all the hard work for me - solved!